# Installing Arch Linux alongside Windows 8

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

I already have Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 8 alongside. (Dual boot)

Now I would like to install Arch Linux instead Ubuntu.

I have seen many Video tutorials about installing Arch Linux but all was about installing in Virtual Machines.

- Do I need to remove Ubuntu before installing Arch ?
- Can I remove Ubuntu when I'm installing Arch in `fdisk` section ?

It's my first trying to install Arch-Linux. I should be careful.

Because I don't want to lose Windows 8.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't overwrite the Ubuntu partitions with the Arch's data in the installation process?

Comment: Because I didn't know that :)

Comment: There is an excellent step-by-step tutorial on [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should format the Ubuntu partition (using a tool like fdisk or cfdisk) and install Arch in that same partition. But you can also keep Ubuntu if you do not wish to remove it. That way, you could end up with 3 options: Arch, Ubuntu and Windows 8 during boot up.

Once you install Arch Linux with a bootloader (like grub or lilo), you will get an option to boot your OS of choice during each boot up, similar to what you might be getting right now.